# Can't enable cache control on apache server

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, pagespeed, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am running a AWS Lightsail Bitnami instance with Wordpress installed. I am trying to enable Cache Control. I have tried adding these directives to the .htaccess file:

```
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have also tried uncommenting this line in httpd.conf:
`LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so`
I added a expires.conf file in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf` folder. I added this code:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

  ExpiresByType image/jpg “access plus 60 days”
  ExpiresByType image/png “access plus 60 days”
  ExpiresByType image/js “access plus 60 days”
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg “access plus 60 days”
  ExpiresByType text/css “access plus 1 days”
</IfModule>
```

I restarted the apache server after these changes. My files are still not being cached. The Lightsail instance comes preconfigured with pagespeed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The Bitnami stacks don't use the information in the .htaccess files due to security and performance reasons. To do so, we configure Apache with "AllowOverride None" and create a htaccess.conf file inside the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf. If you want to include any custom configuration in your app, you will need to edit that file.

You can find more information here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you Jota. That solved the problem for me. I don't know how familiar you are with pagespeed but it comes enabled with AWS Lightsail instances. Many of the filters however are not working such as combining css/js and lazy loading images. Is this related to the bitnami configuration? Do you have any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked. Regarding PageSpeed, we enable it by default. If it's not working properly, it's probably because your instance doesn't have enough memory (RAM) for it to work properly. In that case, I suggest you disable it by commenting the PageSpeed's lines in the apache2/conf/httpd.conf file. More info [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-pagespeed/#disable-pagespeed)

Comment: Thanks Jota. Adding the following code to my `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` file resolved the issue:
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Vary
</IfModule>